# Best open source LINQ provider

Tags: .net, linq, open-source

What's the best open source LINQ provider (in terms of completeness)?

I'm developing an open source LINQ provider myself and I'd like to borrow as many ideas as I can, avoid common pitfalls, etc.

Do not restrict yourself to database LINQ providers, any provider suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Comment to closers: "not constructive"? I learned a lot from the proposed providers. I'd say learning is constructive, but I guess you don't like learning...

Comment: Sorry to say it, but the closing rules do seem a little robotic in the way they are applied.  I guess that's a commonplace observation by now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is another implementation "re-linq".

Have a look here:

- http://www.re-motion.org/blogs/team/archive/2009/04/23/introducing-re-linq-a-general-purpose-linq-provider-infrastructure.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/relinqish_the_pain.aspx

Hope it helps,
Patrick

Comment: re-linq looks promising. very impressed by its power and completeness. will take it for a test drive this weekend.

Answer (score 4):

Our object database [db4o](http://www.db4o.com) comes with an open source LINQ provider. We even provide an implementation for CompactFramework. To my knowledge this is the only LINQ provider available for CompactFramework.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ to Amazon web services.

http://linqinaction.net/files/folders/linqinaction/entry1952.aspx

Comment: LINQ in Action is an excellent book.  Good recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [LINQExtender](http://www.codeplex.com/LinqExtender) for an example of an extendable IQueryable implementation. It not only provides a good open source example, but you may find you could use that instead of developing an IQueryable implementation from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I have a pseudo-LINQ provider: "[Push LINQ](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/01/04/quot-push-quot-linq-revisited-next-attempt-at-an-explanation.aspx)". It's like Parallel Extensions in that it changes how an existing in-memory data source is used, rather than bringing another actual data source into play.

The bits are available as part of my [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) project. It's probably best to ping me privately if you get into it and want to know more (or make suggestions).

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll check it out later at home.

Answer (score 1):

The [DbLinq](http://linq.to/db) project is working on linq2sql support for other databases, and is now [working with the Mono project](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Oct-01-2.html) to become a full System.Data.Linq implementation.

Answer (score 1):

We have a complete linq provider in [Signum Framework](http://www.signumframework.com/DatabaseQuery.ashx)

You can find the source [here](http://signum.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/25903#510381) as well. (All the Linq subtree).

I'ld also take a look to [Wayward blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/)

Answer (score 0):

[LinqExtender](http://www.codeplex.com/LinqExtender) gives a way to get started with LINQ to anything without doing the complex Expression tree parsing. It gives out more or less easy data structure, without sacrificing things like projection , where , order by etc. Its still under development and  a starting point could be [LinqToFlickr](http://www.codeplex.com/linqflickr).

Hope you find it useful and its open to any suggestion

Comment: LINQExtender was already mentioned