# where can I find a LinQ parser

Tags: linq, parsing

I'd like to allow my users to write and execute linq queries.
For this, I need a linq parser. This parser would understand only linq expression, not the full C# language.

So, for example, if we have
class Order
{
public int OrderId;
}
List list = ...

the user should be able to enter in the UI
"select p in list where p.OrderId > 2";
And this would return the orders where orderId > 2.

Does it exist?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to do it is to:

1. Embed the expression into an C# file that will generate a method that will return the query as Expression>; e.g., for

   ```
   from x in Foos select x.Y
   ```

   You might emit:

   ```
   class Wrapper {
       IEnumerable<blah> Foos;
       public static Expression<Func<object>> Expr { 
           get { return from x in Foos select x.Y; } 
       }
   }
   ```
2. Invoke the C# compiler on the file.
3. Load the resulting assembly.
4. Access the property
5. Use the Linq tree to your heart's content.

As a byproduct you get type checking and a bunch of other things. The only real downside is you need a good understanding of the environment in which the query will be executing; if one of the things you're trying to do is to understand the environment, then this doesn't help you very much.

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own Linq providers, here's [a walk through on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx)

Comment: It sounds like you may be wanting to implement your own LINQ _provider_.  This has been covered previously on stackoverflow; see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174585/best-open-source-linq-provider).  A Google search for "LINQ provider" turns up lots of other examples, as well.

Comment: How does it answer my question? I still need to write the parser

Comment: that's the point, you don't, you implement an IQueryable provider and you get the Linq parsing "for free"